# Vagrant SSH & Nano on Linux Mint 17.3

Tags: bash, ssh, linux-mint, vagrant, nano

I've recently installed Vagrant (1.7.4) and VirtualBox (5.0) on 3 laptops each running Linux Mint. Have reached a stage on all 3 where I need to edit a config file on the VM itself. So far, so good.

So having entered

```
vagrant up
```

and then

```
vagrant ssh
```

to get onto the box, then entering

```
nano /path/to/conf
```

to start editing said config file, on one of the machines I get

```
-bash: nano: command not found.
```

The other 2 machines work fine. All 3 have the same OS, same versions of vagrant & virtualbox remember. 2 of the machines are HP laptops, the other is an Asus. It's one of the HP machines that fails.

Now, this only occurs under vagrant ssh. If I just use a standard terminal window, nano works just fine across all 3 machines. Also, I know that I can use vi or vim but that's not the point. Why has nano become unavailable on one of the machines and can it be reinstated for use under vagrant ssh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install nano under the Vagrant user, but the package manager's different to Linux Mint.
If you type `sudo yum install nano` it should work.

Comment: That worked, thank you. Am struggling though as to why it worked on the other 2 machines and not on the third. I thought Vagrant was supposed to install the same VM everywhere?